# how to get the ID of the first word inside a sentence from another table

Tags: mysql, string

I have a table which contains sentences like shown

[image]

and another table which is generated based on this table with all words used by the sentences and their frequencies as shown

[image]

I want to add another column for the first table named Score with the WID of the least word used in that sentence, my expected output is something like this.

[image]

it should always select the first word with least accuracy from the second table

is there a way to do  it using Phpmyadmin and some MySQL query ?

```
create table messages(sent varchar(200), verif int, wid);
insert into messages values
    ('hello my name is alex', null),
    ('hey alin and alex I''m tom', null, null),
    ('hello alex my name is alin', null, null);
```

to generate second table

```
create view words_view as with recursive cte as (
    select 
        substring(concat(sent, ' '), 1, locate(' ', sent)) word,
        substring(concat(sent, ' '), locate(' ', sent) + 1) sent
    from messages
    union all
    select 
        substring(sent, 1, locate(' ', sent)) word,
        substring(sent, locate(' ', sent) + 1) sent
    from cte
    where locate(' ', sent) > 0
)
select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc, word) wid, word, count(*) freq
from cte 
group by word
order by wid
```

now I need to update the wid in the first table with the wid of the least used word in that sentence from second table.

Comment: *"is there a way to do it using Phpmyadmin and some MySQL query ?"* Yes, certainly

Comment: can you help me with it because Im out of ideas for it @Cid

Comment: @Strawberry so you think its not doable ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.sentence
     , w.id 
  FROM words w 
  JOIN sentences s ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.sentence,' ',1) = w.word;
+----------------------------+----+
| sentence                   | id |
+----------------------------+----+
| hello my name is alex      |  3 |
| hello alex my name is alin |  3 |
| hey alin and alex I'm tom  |  8 |
+----------------------------+----+
```

Comment: the first one comes should be selected from the second table

Comment: with the lowest frequency not ID

Comment: i tried SELECT sent
     , wid
  FROM SENT words_view 
  JOIN SENT sent ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(sentence,' ',1) = words_view.wid;

Comment: and it gives me this error #1052 - Column 'sent' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Note that there's no ambiguity in my query, because I qualify ALL column names. Why not do the same?

Comment: tbh I dont know what you did with table names and column names can you do it based on mine ?

Comment: I edited the question check if you can help now please

Comment: Can you provide CREATE and INSERT statements for both tables; I'm not using a version that supports CTE

Comment: you can check here what is done as well https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96f56be611344efb757e83528b04c132   but this does not contain the field that i want to add